# Filename contains variable - how to apply to R functions

Tags: r

`x` is a variable with a name like

```
x <- "Smith"
```

I want to use a function that does something like

```
> write.csv(dataframe,file="Bookkeeping_x.csv")
```

It should return  a file called `Bookkeeping_Smith.csv`

My desired solution is to call a function `> do_bookkeeping(x)` with

```
> do_bookkeeping <- function(x)
> {
  ........
> write.csv(dataframe,file="Bookkeeping_x.csv")
> ........
> }
```

I want the function `do_bookkeeping(x)` to create a file

```
Bookkeeping_Smith.csv
```

Comment: You'd probably be calling it as `do_bookkeeping('smith')` (i.e. with quotes around smith).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
write.csv(dataframe,file=paste0("Bookkeeping_",x,".csv"))
```

Answer (score 1):

`sprintf` is handy for this:

```
do_bookkeeping <- function(x) {
  write.csv(dataframe, file=sprintf('Bookkeeping_%s.csv', x))
}
```

The `%s` is replaced by the second argument to `sprintf`, i.e. `x`.

See `?sprintf` for more details.